# Asking about the location(specifically the name of the room) of a meeting

Tags: questions

A person from the company where I'm working send me an email telling that we are meeting on the 3rd floor, but she forgot to mention the name of the room where we are meeting, so I want to ask her about that. How can I do it properly?

Ways that come to my mind:

> 1: Which room are we meeting at?
>   2:    Which room are we meeting in?
>   3:    In which room are we meeting? (is this even gramatically correct?)
>   4:    What's the room where we are meeting at/in)?
>   5:    What's the name of room where we are meeting at/in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most authentic-sounding is the second.

> Which room are we meeting in?

Option 1 is not valid. You are meeting (I imagine) **in** the room, and not "at" (i.e. outside it).

Option 3 is valid but likely overly formal.

Option 4 is not grammatical. "Where" and "in" do not play nicely together. When combined like this, they become "in which". So, you could potentially say (though I maintain it's formal/archaic): "Where/Which is the room in which we are meeting?".

Answer (score 2):

1. Option **#1** uses "at" incorrectly since you will meet within the room rather than near the room.
2. Option **#2** is correct with regard to grammar.  Some older styleguides may recommend against dangling the preposition, but it is O.K. in this context.
3. Option **#3** is a verbose expansion of **#2**.  Journalistic style would avoid it.
4. Option **#4** is extremely awkward. I would avoid it.

Therefore I would pick **#2.**